# Does the law make exceptions for Good Samaritans?

Tags: criminal-law, court, rules-of-court, good-samaritan

I know very little about the law. When I watch court television shows, it seems like if a Good Samaritan breaks the law to stop a bad guy, the law/court turns a blind eye.

Are there cases where the law recognizes wrongdoing for the well-intentioned but minimizes or ignores the issue?

Comment: Well, TV will tend to misinform you. They're say whatever will glue your eyes to the set to get you to watch commercials.  If you doubt that, pick a subject you really know well, and watch Youtube videos about that subject LOL.   But generally, *mens rea* is the key element of a crime. You also have exigencies as well as literal *Good Samaritan* laws. I leave you to google that!

Comment: Your title is asking about good samaritans, but the body of your question seems to be asking more about vigilante justice--which is it?

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no, it depends upon the instances in question and which place's law is at issue.

Comment: Possibly related/dupe? [Does a Good Samaritan law protect a person from murder charges if they kill someone who had been violently attacking a police officer?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/72394/2618)

Comment: Whilst not explicitly encoded in law, many nations have a concept of Prosecutorial discretion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosecutorial_discretion), where the government can choose to ignore something if its not considered worth prosecuting, which can be used in good samaritan cases.

Comment: This definitely happens in many countries, although you'd have to replace "good samaritan" with "white, wealthy, politician, or otherwise well-known member of the community"

Answer (score 37):

Depends on where you are, and what law would be broken and why.

In [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), there is the concept of *rechtfertigender Notstand* (justifying emergency). If there is a present danger to a *Rechtsgut* (legally protected interest), one can take necessary and proportional steps against another legally protected interest.

Say I walk through a winter landscape and there is a person who has broken through the ice of a lake (a present danger of the loss of life). Nearby is a yard with a ladder leaning on a shed. I would be allowed to enter the yard (normally trespas) and take the ladder (normally theft) in the rescue attempt (life counts for more than a ladder, using a ladder is necessary/appropriate for an ice rescue).

The details are, as usual for Law SE, complicated.

Comment: By the way: When someone causes material damage during a rescue attempt in Germany, for example by breaking said ladder, then compensation for those damages is in most cases covered by the insurance of the rescued person.

Comment: @Philipp, I thought the municipality would cover it.

Comment: Nit:  At least in [tag:england-and-wales] taking the ladder would not be theft, because of the lack of intent to "permanently deprive" - but you might need to break the lock on the ladder (which would normally be criminal damage)

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica, how about an England answer? I just covered my part of the woods.

Comment: @o.m.  Mainly because I don't know whether the criminal damage would be covered by a "with lawful excuse" exemption.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Given that "I was only borrowing it" (really meaning "I didn't get permission but I planned from the start to bring it back") doesn't stop something being _stealing_, at least as children are advised, what is the correct legal classification, if not theft, for taking with only the intent to temporarily deprive?

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica back in the 90s when ramraiding was in fashion in the UK, the culprits weren't charged with theft of the car because they said they were just borrowing it (or TWOC-ing it - taking without consent) which has a maximum sentence of 6 months, as opposed to 7 years for theft ([random internet link](https://www.burtoncopeland.com/news/twoc-and-vehicle-theft-burton-copeland-explain-difference/))

Comment: @J.G.  I don't know.  There is the specific offense of "taking without consent" if the item is a motor vehicle.  I suspect anything else you would be looking at "criminal damage" (e.g. for the wear on the ladder rungs).  Speaking personally, I don't think I taught my son that borrowing something without permission was _stealing_.

Comment: @Philipp is personal liability insurance fairly ubiquitous in Germany? It's not in the UK, you might have it if you have home and contents insurance, but that's a lot of people that aren't covered.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Here are study materials on the relevant §242 StGB "theft": https://www.juracademy.de/strafrecht-bt2/diebstahl-subjektiver-tatbestand.html#b-enteignungsvorsatz Basically, German criminal law doesn't punish unauthorized borrowing except for cars and bikes (§248b). If o.m. fails to give back the ladder, it's technically theft. If returning the ladder would entail unreasonable risks or burdens, the defense of a justifying emergency applies. Details.

Comment: Also note that in Germany, acting as a good samaritan is basically a duty, not merely a right. §323c StGB.

Comment: @Joooeey Thanks.  This is useful to know (given I know live in Germany).

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica, a claim that you *really, truly* did plan to give it back might not be believed, unless there are compelling circumstances.

Answer (score 26):

While the question asks generally about "necessity"-type defenses, there is a need to distinguish between two separate concepts.

### Good Samaritan laws

[Good samaritan laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Samaritan_law) "offer legal protection to people who give reasonable assistance to those who are, or whom they believe to be injured, ill, in peril, or otherwise incapacitated".

The typical example would be attempting CPR on an unconscious person and breaking one of their ribs. Breaking someone’s rib would usually be a tort, but as long as the rescue attempt was done in a "reasonable" manner, the rescuer will not be on the hook for medical costs. What is "reasonable" varies across jurisdictions.

Those laws usually imply a subjective element. If a random person at the site of a car crash moves an unconscious body on the curbside to free the road for traffic, that’s probably reasonable. If a first-aid instructor does it, less so (such a person would know that trauma victims should not be moved unless strictly necessary). If the same first-aid instructor moves an unconscious body away from a riverside bed during heavy rain, that might be reasonable; even if it later turns out the rain subsided and no flood occurs, that was a reasonable concern at the time the decision had to be taken.

At [common-law](/questions/tagged/common-law), those laws only apply when the rescuer has no duty of care. For instance, suppose a ferris wheel I was riding suddenly catches fire. The ferris wheel operator stops the wheel, sets up mattresses below and asks patrons to jump down onto them to get to safety. By doing so, I break my rib. The ferris wheel operator might not be on the hook for my broken rib, assuming the "jump onto mattresses" rescue plan was the only one available at the time. However, the ferris wheel owner still had a duty of care towards patrons, and should have provided a safe environment that did not require jumping from the height of the wheel. I can therefore still sue for medical expenses. The Good Samaritan law does not "erase" liability caused by creating the dangerous circumstances in the first place.

[civil-legal-system](/questions/tagged/civil-legal-system) would roughly follow the same principles (no tort during a reasonable rescue attempt). The only significant addition is (in most but not all civil law countries) a duty to rescue. The rescue only need be "reasonable" - for instance, if you see a child drowning in the river, you must call the emergency services, but you usually do not have to try to go into the water yourself (because that would put yourself at risk). However, the risk calculation changes depending on whether you are an eighty-year-old teacher or a thirty-year-old Olympic swimmer.

Those laws are about limiting the liability of the rescuer towards the rescued. They do not cover relations with third parties (such as a bad guy on the scene).

### Self-defense

Self-defense is the act of defending against a threat via violent (and otherwise illegal) means. The exact scope of self-defense varies across jurisdictions, but to my knowledge it always extends to defending *others* against a "bad guy", not necessary oneself. (The English "self"-defense is a bit misleading in that respect. The French, Spanish or Italian term translates to "legitimate defense"; the German or Dutch term translates to "necessity/urgency defense".) The scope of what is allowed under which circumstances depends a lot across jurisdictions.

In general, the defense requires a reasonable subjective belief that the threat is imminent (you don’t get to shoot a murderer fleeing the scene), and that the countermeasures taken be proportionate (you don’t get to shoot a brat who is tickling your child).

Some jurisdictions and circumstances require that no otherwise-legal course of action be reasonable (typically, when defending against a threat to yourself, that you cannot flee the scene). Others allow it regardless. Some jurisdictions and circumstances allow lethal action against a threat towards goods; others do not.

Comment: Most "Good Samaritan" Laws include a "Life over Limb" clause that will protect first responders from suit if, in the course of competently administered care, an injury occurs in an attempt to save a life.  CPR, for example, when administered correctly, will cause injury to the victim.  However, considering it was done to prevent death by a lack of oxygen to the brain, the Good Sam law presumes that the victim would have consented to by the victim as if they had they been conscious.  Your ferryman example, supposing it was within his training would fall under this.

Comment: @hszmv you are correct. My example was unclear, I edited it.

Comment: In the USA, there is also a capability clause. The rescuer should not perform any measures for which he is not trained. Ex: I could perform CPR to save a life. I could not legally perform a tracheotomy to save a life, because I am not trained to do such a thing, If I did, I could be opening myself up for a lawsuit by the victim/victims family.

Comment: @ScottieH That depends. There's no one rule for the entire USA on this.

Comment: And obviously good samaritan laws do NOT cover criminal liability. If you knife a bystander to get his belt so you can use it as a tourniquet to stem the bleeding of someone else's wound, you're still going to get arrested for assault.

Comment: @jwenting isn't theft a criminal liability?

Comment: @KFK: I think there's a typo "murdered fleeing the scene" should probably be "murderer..."? (Can't submit edit for a single character...)

Comment: @user253751 less severe than assault... And using the belt would likely fall under good samaritan protection if you picked it up from a store display for that use, but NOT when you take it from the corpse of the guy you just stabbed

Comment: *"If a first-aid instructor does it, less so (such a person would know that trauma victims should not be moved unless strictly necessary)"* The very first thing a first-aid responder would do is remove risks of escalation. For a trauma victim in the middle of a road, this means making sure the victim won't be run over a second time, either by placing orange cones on the road if that's safe enough, or by moving the victim off the road if the road is deemed too dangerous, even at the risk of worsening the injury. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) So if a trauma instructor had indeed moved a victim off the road to free the road for traffic, and subsequently ended in legal trouble, they would most likely argue they did it not to free the road for traffic, but to move the victim to safety.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for this awesome answer which compares multiple jurisdictions!

Comment: Self defense also requires that you didn't provoke the attack, under whatever the jurisdiction's definition of provoke is, or if you did then you made an effort to deescalate, under that jurisdiction's ways to reacquire a privilege of self defense.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons the US Constitution protect the right to a jury trial is that juries will sometimes recognize their right and duty to acquit people who have violated a statute whose enforcement in the case before them would be offensive to principles of justice and freedom.  If all twelve jurors, seeing the defendant's actions, would be inclined to admit that they would likely have done the same thing in the defendant's situation, they should unanimously vote for acquittal regardless of what the statutes may say.

Judges and prosecutors don't want jurors to be aware of this right and duty, but it nonetheless may influence decisions about what cases to prosecute.  If the public as a whole would believe that the defendant behaved in a manner contrary to statute, but justice and freedom would be ill served by a conviction, prosecuting the defendant could attract attention to the jury's rights and duties--attention that prosecutors really don't want.